# X.PagedList change property in subset

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I'm using [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList).
After getting IPagedList result, I need to modify some properties inside currenct subset (items on current page). And only after that my function will return PagedList result.

How can I modify current page elements?

Answer (score 0):

Answer inside [example on github](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList#example):

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

        // Modify current page elements (onePageOfProducts) here 

        ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
        return View();
    }
}
```

`var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);` will return current page elements, which you can modify (by modifying elements inside var `onePageOfProducts`) right after that.

Comment: I already has a function which returns onePageOfProducts, I need to modify elements, and return onePageOfProducts from another function. I guess only way to do is with foreach loop. Can we do that with linq?